# Updating pandas dataframe using Dash

Tags: python, plotly-dash

Hi I am wondering if its possible to develop a dashboard where some inputs (from check boxes/radio items etc.) can update pandas dataframe in the backend.
Basically I am trying to develop a data labeling tool. For example, an image is shown in the dashboard and you pick several classes using check boxes after which you click on a submission button which populates the entries to a pandas dataframe which can eventually be saved into a csv file.

```
app.layout = html.Div([

    # Dropdown selection that will be used to select some image
    html.Div([
        dcc.Dropdown(id = "image-folders", options = [{"label" : i, "value" : i} for i in folders, value = folders[0]]
    ]),
    
    # Graph goes here ...
    html.Div([
        dcc.Graph(id = "image-graph", figure :{}) # Returns a plotly graph through a callback
    ])

    # Checkboxes go here - Selected values should be updated in the dataframe
    html.Div([
        dcc.Checklist(id = "labels-checklist", options = [{"label" : "Agriculture" , "value" : "Agriculture"}, {"label" : "Residential", "value" : "Residential"}])
    ])
    
    # Submission button goes here - Click submit to append selected values from checklist to a dataframe and then move on to the next image using the drop down and do the same
    html.Button(id = "submission-button", n_clicks = 0, children = "Submit")
])

# Callback & function to update figure
@callback(Output("image-graph","figure"), Input("image-folders", "value))

def update_figure(img_folder):
    file_path = os.path.join(root, img_folder)
    img = skimage.io.imread(file_path)
    fig = px.imshow(img)
    return fig
```

Now I basically need to write another callback that takes values from the "labels-checklist" and append it to a data frame. This doesn't necessarily need to be shown in the dashboard, but I read in few places that callbacks need both an Input and Output. So if it appears in some dash table that's fine. But its not really necessary in my case. Any idea how to do this ?

```
# Ideally no Output
@callback([Input("label-checklist","value"), Inputs("submission-button")])

def populate_dataframe(nclicks, checklist_value):
    # need help what goes here and what output I have to give
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should make an empty dataframe then append your Checklist value to it. Something as below may work:

```
import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_table
import pandas as pd
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

form = pd.DataFrame({'A':[]})

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div([
        dcc.Checklist(id = "labels-checklist",
                      options = [{"label" : "Agriculture" , "value" : "Agriculture"}, 
                                 {"label" : "Residential", "value" : "Residential"}])
    ]),
    
    # Submission button goes here - Click submit to append selected values from checklist to a dataframe and then move on to the next image using the drop down and do the same
    html.Button(id = "submission-button", n_clicks = 0, children = "Submit"),
    dash_table.DataTable(id='table', data=[], columns=[{"name":i, "id":i} for i in form.columns])
])

@app.callback(Output('table', 'data'),
             [Input('submission-button', 'n_clicks')],
             [State('table', 'data'),
              State('table', 'columns')] + [State('labels-checklist', 'value')])

def add_row(n_clicks, rows, columns, labels):
    if n_clicks >0:
        rows.append({c['id']: r for c, r in zip(columns, labels)})
    return rows

def update_data(labels):
    data = pd.DataFrame({'A':[labels]})
    return data.to_dict(orient="records")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

[image]